# Can you choose which pages show "add to homescreen"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I'm setting up a PWA and would ideally like the "add to homescreen" message to show on a specific page as it adds the most context to the web app.

Comment: You can intercept the beforeinstallprompt, and then place an install button wherever you like.

Comment: @Mathias Sorry how would I do that, with an event listener?

Comment: Plenty of examples out there with code: https://web.dev/customize-install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I intercepted the beforeinstallprompt event.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
})
```